# Kubuntu activity switching problems

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, kde, panel, plasma

Coming from Ubuntu I'm trying out activities in Kubuntu/KDE to improve my workflow.

**Activities** are separate sets of virtual desktops targeted for special tasks on a computer like default, coding, or photography. 
**Activities** is for organizing **tasks**, **desktops** for organizing **windows** in that task.

You can set up different shortcuts, desktop widgets and backgrounds to see which activity your're on. Doesn't work well using maximized windows.

Switching activities goes with META TAB. Unfortunately the Activity taskbar is not scrolling (bug ??), so with more then 5 you can't see which activity you're switching to. Shortcuts to switch to activity X are not working, (not saved [bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=342186) or [this](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=374575) ??)

Activity pager  and activity bar are huge widgets with > 6 activities.

Is there a panel widget that shows the name of the activity (or number), and when you click/hover let you choose an activity from a dropdown list?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set Activity manager on Kubuntu there is many options like Screen Edges, Widgets and shortcuts.

1) **Screen Edges :** Go on **System Setting -> Desktop Behavior -> Screen Edges** [image: Activity Manager]

Click on one of Screen edge and set to **Activity Manager -> Apply**

2) **Widgets :** Right click on **Desktop -> Add Widgets ->** then select **Activity Pager**  then Activity Pager place to your Desktop.

3) **Shortcuts :** To Enable Shortcuts Go on **System Settings -> Desktop Behavior -> Activities(Main setting of Activities)**  and [image: Activity Manager1]click on Button near to Remove then **Add your Shortcuts**.

**From There you can also set your Activity Name.**

And in activity setting there is a **bar(Activities | Switching | Privacy).**

4) **From Privacy you can limit your App**.

[image]

Comment: Nice! There's also the Activity bar. If you want, you can add that to your answer as well.

Comment: Thx, but widgets on a desktop are covered by programs.
 (I have Firefox shown in every activity.)
Widget in panels are too wide (6>act). 
Shortcuts to switch to activity XX are broken.

Comment: Is there a way to set the width of the Activity Manager, and height of the screens. I prefer it to be smaller.

Comment: If you want to remove firefox then you can. Firefox comes by default in Kubuntu machine. You can set your shortcuts in Activity setting.

Comment: No, Firefox is OK. I would prefer proper and fast keyboard switching in activities, and prefer a visual indication on the panel which activity is active, because the desktop is covered. Like said in my question, existing activity widgets are too spacious IMHO. Is it possible to create a fading (to the background) widget, that shows for a second the name of the activity, when that is changed.?

Comment: Ok. I got it. Have you seen Activity Pager in Widgets option. Just drag that Activity Pager in your application menu bar. It will show you all activity pages in one location then assign shortcuts to all pages. Hope this will help.

Comment: I've added screenshot in my answer. Look at 3rd image.

Comment: Thx, I found the shortcuts tab before. Problem it's broken in 18.04: not saved, and don't work. And like written in the question, I do think the pager widget is too wide with >6 activities. I use global menus.